# How to escape characters in a PDO update of MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo

If the $value has an apostrophe ( ' ) in it the following won't update the MySQL data base. How do I escape the character(s)?

```
$sql = "UPDATE NetLog SET $column = :val WHERE recordID = :rec_id";

            $stmt = $db_found->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':val', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':rec_id', $recordID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You tried the code? Should work because `prepare` and `execute` should escape such a character. But you forget to bind the parameter for `:req_id`.

Comment: I had taken the rec_id bind out out for clarity, but that only confused the issue. As to trying the code, yes I use it in this application a lot. Today maybe for the first time I tried to use a $value that looked like this (minus the quotes);   $value = "Ain't that cool?"   and it failed. So I removed all words one at a time until I learned it was Ain't causing the issue.

Comment: Is the quote possibly a smart-quote type special character that might be causing character set issues?  (though even then I'd generally expect MySQL to just convert it into something less desirable...)

Comment: That should work presuming the character sets match. Ideally you use UTF-8 all the way through. There's a world of difference between "Ain't" and "Ain’t" even though they're visually very similar.

Comment: You said it doesn't update -- does it just silently fail to update, or does it throw an error?  If the latter, please edit to include the error.  If the former, perhaps there's a problem with the value being passed in as `:rec_id` which is causing the `WHERE` clause to not match any records - maybe print `$recordID` out to confirm that the value is what you expect it to be?

Comment: At the time of failure I see nothing about an error. However if I use inspector I see it failed because; "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" but there is no detail with it.